# syntax error in recursive function using rows from a multidimentional array in c

Tags: c, recursion, multidimensional-array, arguments

Im trying to access a specific row in a multidimensional array, sow that it acts like the vector in the following program that finds the highest value in the vector:

```
int getMax(int V[], int i){
if(i<0){
    return V[0];
}
else{
    return max(V[i], getMax(V, i-1));
}
```

The error in the following is

> passing arugment to parameter 'a' here

```
#define N 3
#define M 2

int array_print_max(int a[N][M], int i , int j) // error is in this line.
{
if(i<0)
 {
    return a[j][0];
 }
else
 {
    return max(a[j][i], array_print_max(a[j][i-1], i-1 , j));
 }
}
```

In both cases the max function is:

```
int max(int a, int b)
{
if (a > b)
 {
    return a;
 }
else
 {
    return b;
 }
}
```

Main is

```
int main()
{
int a[3][2] = { {0,4,2}, {1,2,3} };
}
```

Why wont the funtion `array_print_max` compline?

Comment: `array_print_max(a[j][i-1], i-1 , j)` attempts to pass an `int` argument for an `array` parameter. How is that supposed to work, you reckon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following warnings:

Excess elements in main:

```
int a[3][2] = { {0,4,2}, {1,2,3} };
```

Should be:

```
int a[2][3] = { {0,4,2}, {1,2,3} };
```

Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int':

```
return max(a[j][i], array_print_max(a[j][i-1], i-1 , j));
```

maybe this should be:

```
return max(a[j][i], array_print_max(a, i-1 , j));
```

This is because the prototype requires an array of arrays, but `a[j][i-1]` is an `int`.

and of course I got a warning about unused variable 'a' in `main`.

`int array_print_max(int a[N][M], int i , int j)`

In `int a[N][M]` the first value here, `N`, is ignored.  it doesn't usually raise a compilation error though.  In addition, we changed the array dimensions, so the following is less misleading:

```
int array_print_max(int a[][N], int i , int j)
```

Comment: Then printing the result of 'array_print_max' as `int p = array_print_max(a,2,3); printf("%d",p);` I get the original error in the same line as before. I have also tried `int p = array_print_max(a,1,2);` thinking that the first element is a[0][0]. What Im I doing wrong? @cdarke

Comment: Good point!  The prototype for `array_print_max` should be `int array_print_max(int a[][N], int i , int j)`.  I'll update my answer.  However you appear to have a logic issue as well which I will look into.

Comment: Try: `int p = array_print_max(a,2,1);`.

Comment: This is the most strange I have ever encountered. Im using `int p = array_print_max(a,2,1);` It does not work if I change one thing (I added `\n` to the print) and then build and run, but if builds and runs without errors after the first try. This is truly strange. I think I have to restart CodeBlocks and my computer. Anyways thank you! @cdarke

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your main() block of code.

a[m][n] is a 2-D array with "m" rows and "n" columns.But you have defined it vice versa.

```
    int main()
    {
        int a[3][2] = { {0,4,2}, {1,2,3} };
    }
```

but

```
    { 
      {0,4,2}, 
      {1,2,3} 
    }
```

is a 2-D array with 2 rows and 3 columns.
So change your code of main() to

```
    int main()
    {
        int a[2][3] = { {0,4,2}, {1,2,3} };
    }
```

and check once.

Even after that if you get error then feel free to notify me once again.
Good Luck!

Comment: I swapped the two but the same error still appears, the error saying 'passing arugment to parameter 'a' here' still in the same line.

Comment: That's only one of the problems.